# oData expand for VizFrames

Tags: odata, sapui5

Hi I am trying to use oData expand in a vizFrame(pie chart).
My entitySet for the Chart is grouped by their, ... well group.
But the entitySet only has the key of the group, the text and other data are in an associated entitySet.

I tried to use expand just I would use it in tables:

```
viz.data:FlattenedDataset data="{
    path: 'odataModel>myEntitySet',
    parameters: {
        expand: 'toAssoc'
    }
}">    
....

<viz.data:dimensions>
    <viz.data:DimensionDefinition name="Matrialgruppe"
        value="{odataModel>toAssoc/myText}" />
</viz.data:dimensions>
```

It does not work.
I dont get any error in the consol, but where the chart should be I get the text:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

How can I make expand work for VizFrames?

Comment: The message implies you're not dealing with valid JSON somewhere. Chromium based browsers have some methods of tracking where it comes from, either the function that throws the error has a chain, or the initiator of the request in your network tab

Comment: Maybe `myText` is `undefined` at some point? That would explain the `token u`

Comment: where is the myText property? @Marc

Comment: @jorg the json of the odata request is fine, I tryed displaying the same data in a m.table and it worked